# mapping a horizontal strip to open disc

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

Let $S$ be the strip $S := \{ z \in \mathbb{C}  \mid  − \pi < \operatorname{Im}(z) < \pi\}$. Construct a biholomorphic mapping of $S$ onto $D$ where $D$ is unit open disc.

My attempt : I know that the existence of such maps is obtained by Riemann mapping theorem. I think the following  holomorphic map works $ z \mapsto \frac{e^{z/2} -1}{e^{z/2} +1}$
Do I need to show this more rigorously ?

Comment: I set $S := \{ z \in \mathbb{C}  \mid  − \pi < \operatorname{Im}(z) < \pi\}$ with both $\{\text{curly braces}\}$ _inside_ of MathJax, thus assuring proper spacing and matching fonts and sizes. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your map is correct, but shouldn't you show the steps at least graphically? First one brings you to a thinner strip, second one brings you to the right half-plane, and the third one finishes.

Comment: thats what I am stuck at. I mean I am unable  to explain that part properly.

Comment: @SMath: Which part? Just draw the regions before and after the map and label the important points like where the region boundary cuts the axes. Of course this is not rigorous. If you want rigour you will have to prove it algebraically.. Like $(z \mapsto \frac{z}{2})$ is clearly bijective and maps $\{ z : z \in \mathbb{C} \land |Im(z)| < π \}$ to $\{ z : z \in \mathbb{C} \land |Im(z)| < \frac{1}{2}π \}$, which is then mapped by $(z \mapsto e^z)$ to $\{ e^{x+yi} : x,y \in \mathbb{R} \land |y| < \frac{1}{2}π \}$ which is not hard to prove that it's the right half-plane, and so on..

Comment: @SMath: My answer was because you asked "do we need to show this more rigorously", and I believe in most introduction complex analysis courses it's not expected (too tedious). If instead you want to ask "how do we show this completely rigorously", that's a different question, and my previous comment sketches how to do so.

Comment: Thank. I also wanted 'How to show' and your previous comment explains it verywell using which I am able to understand it better now.

Comment: @SMath: Great! If you need any further explanation do not hesitate to ask again!