# Is there other method to map $G$ to $D$ using holomorphic functions?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to map G to D using holomorphic function where
$$
G = \{ z\in\mathbb{C}: Re(z) + 1 < Imz < Re(z) + 3 \}
$$
$$
D = \{ w \in \mathbb{C}: Im(w) < 0, w(2i) = -2i \}
$$
Here what i did.

1. $w_{1} = z - 1$
2. $w_{2} = w_{1}e^{-i\frac{\pi}{4}}$
3. $w_{3} = \sqrt2\pi w_{2}$
4. $w_{4} = e^{w_{3}}$
5. $w_{5} = e^{i\pi} w_{4}$

$$
w = e^{i\pi}e^{w_{3}} = e^{\pi + \sqrt2\pi w_{2}} = e^{\pi + \sqrt2\pi w_{1}e^{-i\frac{\pi}{4}}} = \text{notice that } e^{-i\frac{\pi}{4}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}(1 - i) = e^{\pi((1-i)(z-1)+i)}
$$
but $w(2i) \not = -2i$

> I'm looking for other solution or a place where I did mistake

Answer (score 1):

You meant $D = \{ w \in \mathbb{C}: Im(w) < 0\}$ and $f$ is a biholomorphic map $G\to D$ such that $f(2i)=-2i$.

Construct a biholomorphic map $\phi_1$ from $D$ to the unit disk,

a biholomorphic map $\phi_2$ from $G$ to $|\Im(z)|<\pi$,

[a biholomorphic map $\phi_3$ from $|\Im(z)|<\pi$ to the unit disk](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1735615/276986),

then look at $f=\phi_4\circ \phi_1^{-1}\circ \phi_3 \circ \phi_2$ where $\phi_4\in Aut(D)=PSL_2(\Bbb{R})$ which acts transitively on $D$.

Note that from the stabilizer of $-i$ which is $PSO_2(\Bbb{R})$ we know the stabilizer of $-2i$ and hence all the $f$ satisfying the hypothesis.